# Inflating TextView and LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android

The problem here I don't get the same output view result in these two cases, I want to fix case 1 to get same output result as case 2:

1. Inflate textview and linearlayout, and then add textview to linearlayout programmatically.
2. Add textview to linearlayout in xml.

**Code and Output For Case 1:**

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

text_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
 />
```

onCreate method in LayoutTestActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout lt = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);
    lt.addView(tv);
    setContentView(lt);
}
```

output view (Not Correct)

[image]

**Code and Output For Case 2:**

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

onCreate method in LayoutTestActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

output view (Correct)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if it makes any difference - but my suggestion is this:

Provide the `android:id="@+id/linearLayout"`-tag for the `LinearLayout` in your `main.xml`.

Then do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout lt = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.linearLayout );
    TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);
    lt.addView(tv);
}
```

You might also want to test if there is a difference between supplying `null` or your `LinearLayout lt` as the second parameter when inflating the `TextView` e.g.:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view, lt);
```

Comment: I try your solution but it dose not give the same output as case 2. Thanks for your trying.

Comment: Try posting pictures of the difference in the to layouts - It might reveal what the problem is.

Comment: I posted pictures as you ask, I hope so this will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think in the first place that you have  to set the main layout in the setContentView() method directly and afterwards make the inflate.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
   LinearLayout mainLayout = (Linearlayout) findViewbyId(R.id.mainLayoutId);

   TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view, mainLayout, false);
   mainLayout.addView(tv);
```

I think this way it should work.
To keep the xml layout params you have to pass the last two parameters to the inflate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the LayoutParams in the first case. In the second this is done automatically since TextView is in the xml. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it happens in the first case automatically also because he inflates a view from an xml where the layoutparams are set.

Comment: Dimitris Makris, your answer is work but as Raz said it should be happens automatically. I hope so there is another solution. Thanks both of you.